# Set nice names in custom package in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, multilingual

How can nice names be set when creating a custom package for Laravel 5?

I am creating a custom package and I would like to set some nice names for the form fields specific of the package. Of course I can create a new validation.php for the package and there...

```
return [   
    'attributes' => [
        'max_file_size' => 'Tamaño máximo del archivo'
    ],
];
```

But I don't want to write again all the validation rules. I just want to add some attributes. How this can be done? And how can the validation.php file of a package be called?